# HAML and Rails3 controller-specific layout not rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, layout, haml

I have a Users controller and a layout called 'users.html.haml'.  The problem I'm having is that Rails does not seem to find the users layout automatically.  I have to tell every action in the Users controller to render the layout.  If I don't tell the action which layout to use, it renders no layout at all.

Currently, the layout renders only if the controller action has this line:

```
render :layout=>'users.html.haml'
```

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
I'm an idiot. I overwrote the "initialize" method in application controller, and it was causing all layouts to be loaded improperly unless I specifically told the action which layout to use.  Didn't have anything to do with haml after all.  Thanks for all your answers.

Answer (score 2):

You havev the users.html.haml in your

app/views/layouts

directory right?  And not your app/views/users directory?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
render :layout=>'users'
```

NOTE: I have removed the .haml.html part, because that isn't necessary

Other this you can do is to have the layout in top of the controller, like

```
layout 'users'
```

Edit: and like @Noli said, your layouts should be in app/views/layouts path